# ExpressJS - Sending Data to ReactJS - ExpressJS Route Rendering

Tags: json, reactjs, express

I am fairly new to ReactJS and have comfortably been able to add webpack and the appropriate loaders to enable Babel and ReactJS within my ExpressJS application, but I'm trying to figure out how I can pass data from a rendered View with JSON objects to my ReactJS components. Is this specific action best done with a ReactJS state container like Redux or React Router? Can this also be done without them?

Any resources to understand this communication process would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you intend to make ajax calls? You could use axios for that.

Comment: For some features of my application, but at the moment I'm just trying to determine the best practice for sending data to ReactJS from a rendered view